# ValueError: could not convert string to float - python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm new in **ML**. I created a dataset with some images for digits recognition. I would like to train my model but I have an error when fitting.

I've tried to encode urls numpy array but it doesn't work:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
urls = le.fit_transform(urls)
```

```
import json
import json_lines
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import preprocessing
import sklearn

urls=[]
labels =[]

with open('Digits_file.json') as file1:
    lis = []
    for i in json_lines.reader(file1):
        lis.append(i)

for i in lis:
    urls.append(i['content'])
    labels.append([i['annotation']['labels'][0]])

urls = np.array(urls)
labels = np.array(labels) 

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(urls, labels, test_size=0.2)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[98,98]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

## I got the error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) 
>    in 
>   ----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb06abf8f13016aea188d5c036c/c0e1ad90-fec9-4609-b6d8-65b7efb5263c___0001_CH4M_0_number-25.png'

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It appears that you tried to add different type values to the same array. As per docs: 'A numpy array is a grid of values, all of the same type, and is indexed by a tuple of nonnegative integers.'

Comment: @Alex Bodnya, urls array contains the urls of the images, nothing else. I don't understand whhat you mean.

Comment: Where exactly does the error happen? Please include the full error trace. And please include your full imports (is this scikit-learns's label encoder?)

Comment: @desertnaut the error happens in fit function. 
Sorry, I am not able to include all the trace of the error I have formatting problems

Answer (score 0):

First of all, String data can be the x_train data.

You should an identification of data for learning.
From Your code, It seems that you want to learn `annotation` or `label` by `contents`.
I think `contents` would be natural language.

For the basic NLP (Natural language processing), We should do identification process.
I got some good answer from other answer. Please refer it.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/machine-learning-identification-and-classification-based-on-string-contents-ge

And, You need other preprocessing if training data are images. I got some good answer from other answer. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/how-to-prepare-augment-images-for-neural-network

Comment: I'm trying to do image classification and my json file is structured like this :  `{"content": "http://com.dataturks.a96-i23.open.s3.amazonaws.com/2c9fafb06abf8f13016aea188d5c036c/e066aaa7-4613-43b9-8d99-3b0de246b9d3___0001_CH4M_3_number-3.png","annotation":{"labels":["3"],"note":""},"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1558707816000,"last_updated_at":1558707816000,"sec_taken":2,"last_updated_by":"YuYRnQimm7eP99xIJ8sjwk9CY5D2","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}`

Comment: @kst92 Do you want to get some image by `urls.append(i['content'])` code? You need some pre-processing for training data even though it's images. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/how-to-prepare-augment-images-for-neural-network

Comment: yes that's what I would like to do. I don't know if it's the right procedure. As pre-processing I tried a normalization that didn't work

Comment: @kst92 It's more complicated job than normalization. You need to download images first. And, Resizing and Cropping are required if images have different size and quality.